# Foundation hide-for-small not working

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries, zurb-foundation

I am trying to use foundations `hide-for-small` class to hide my navbar on mobile. It doesn't appear to be having any affect. As far as I understand

```
<h1 class="hide-for-small">Hidden on Mobile</h1>
```

should show the element on my computer, but hide it on my iPhone.

What am I missing?

Comment: Not `hide-for-small-only` ?

Comment: I tried that too, no difference.

Comment: Do you have that class defined in your CSS? It's part of the `_visibility.scss` file. Also, inspect the <h1> in Chrome developer tools or Firebug in Firefox and shrink the window below 768px wide – if it's still displaying, what's the CSS explanation for that?

Comment: Yes, the class is defined. When I shrink the window down the element disappears, but it is still showing up on my iphone for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out it was a simple mistake, I left out my viewport meta tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```